# Why is my HTML not rendering CSS when sent through express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a starter at REST APIs and I'm still beginning to comprehend it. I wanted to do it for a website.

So, I just used **res.sendFile()**, It worked but, The CSS is not being rendered nor does the JS.

Why? Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```js
const app = require("express")()
const PORT = 8000

/**
 * 
 * @param {string} name 
 * @returns 
 * 
 */

function getHTML(name) {
    return process.cwd() + "/html" + `/${name}` + `/${name}.html`
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {string} name 
 * @returns 
 * 
 */


app.get("/password-generator", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(getHTML("password-generator"))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Website is on!")
})
```

A picture of my file structure:

[image: File Structure]

Comment: There is no route for the CSS file.

Comment: Elaborate on what I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to serve the css file as well, not only the html.

The easiest approach would be to use static:

Replace your `app.get` and `getHTML` functions with just this one line:

```js
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/html"));
```

And then you can access your html file with just `http://localhost:8000/password-generator/password-generator.html`

---

Alternate solution: If you want to keep the code you already have and still access it through `http://localhost:8000/password-generator`
then you can just make a separate function to get the css:

```js
app.get("/password-generator/style.css", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + "/html/password-generator/style.css");
});
```

or something of the sort
and then in your html make sure you link to `src="/password-generator/style.css"` instead of `src="style.css"`

Comment: Thanks! It worked, Though, Does other apps that use Express use this method as well? Cause, I heard that a website like Youtube uses REST API and does not look similar to this approach.

Comment: @Baselistic I would think most express apps use this method, not sure about what youtube does

Answer (score -2):

This is happening because css is not compatible with express.

Comment: Wait, So I can't do anything about it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).